# Do I need Bitcoin-qt to run Armory?

Tags: bitcoin-core, armory

Do I need Bitcoin-qt to run Armory? I keep hearing conflicting information.

My goal is to mine bitcoins in a pool, so ideally, I want a very secure wallet, and I would prefer not to download the entire blockchain if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

**Armory by default doesnt run Bitcoin-qt, it runs Bitcoind**. Since armory installs the entire Bitcoin reference client by default, Bitcoin-qt will be present regardless (you can try to delete it, though):

> Bitcoin-Qt is the “Graphical User Interface” around the core Bitcoin
>   protocol that is run by the majority of nodes on the network. 
>   ”bitcoind” is the same software but without the user interface — it is
>   simply a process that runs in the background and only allows access to
>   it through its API.  For the purposes of running Armory, either one is
>   sufficient, but one of them must be running and synchronized.  The
>   latest version of Armory will run bitcoind for you in the background.

**Armory/Bitcoind does need to download the entire blockchain**:

> Regardless of which one you use, it will download the entire
>   blockchain

Source for both snips: https://bitcoinarmory.com/about/armory-and-bitcoin-qt/

Comment: I don't recall Armory installing Bitcoin-QT by default.  I'm pretty sure you have to download QT and install it yourself.

Comment: @ChrisW you are right. You have to install it by yourself (at least, in the current version of Armory which is 0.96)